# Get Developer Mode Source Code (F12) of a Web Page using C# (Dynamic Source of a web)

Tags: c#, html, .net, google-chrome

I'm trying to get the source code of a web page using C#,I get the base source code but most of the data is dynamically generated after. How can obtain the final source code filled with data? (Same Like Developer Option in Google Chrome & IE)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to wait for the page to load completely and call your c# functionality asynchronus afterwards.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () { $.ajax("example.cs/MyWebMethod");});
```

And in c# you got something like

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public void MyWebMethod() { 
//..do stuff
}
```

If the `ready` event is also "too early" you could just set a timeout in jscript and call the WebMethod after a set timeperiod

Comment: I don't want to read the source code same time of a page load, Just I need to know whatever the changes occuring dynamically when a web page is active

Comment: @SoorajBathery just for my understanding: You want to catch the event whenever the content of an active Website changes?